# iPhone Simulator Text Box Takes up Whole Screen

Tags: iphone

Here is my code. Not sure what's awry.

controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ch4iOSPracticeViewController : UIViewController {

UITextField *nameField;
UITextField *numberField;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;

@end
```

controller.m

```
#import "ch4iOSPracticeViewController.h"

@implementation ch4iOSPracticeViewController
@synthesize nameField;
@synthesize numberField;
```

delegate.m Everything properly released.

```
- (void)dealloc {
[viewController release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
```

}

[image: Here is what it's supposed to look like.]

[image: here is what it looks like now.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a textField to the iPhone using interface builder, I am guessing that there was another view already present there; So when you pulled the textField over it, it had stretched. Try pulling it inside a plain View.

It is either that you pulled a textview instead of a textfield.

Comment: Oh. So you can't command-c and paste a new textfield? I put down one, and then copy and pasted a new one within the interface rather than dragging in a new one.

Comment: Just open the nib file, open the view which has the guitar picture and name labels and stuff and place it there. Make sure that you connect the outlets properly to the textFields

Comment: Tried putting in a whole new textField. Didn't work. I first added the guitar image, and then the two textFields.

Comment: Please do this. Delete all views. Add an UIView on the iphone. Place the guitar image, and the two textfields. It should work now.

Comment: If you still have doubts. Please watch this tutorial. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_KaTlRC2ao&feature=fvwrel

Comment: Ah. I never added a UIView. Though, when I launch the simulator now, it crashes. Do I need a to vary my code at all now that I've added a UIView to the nib?

Comment: Not really. It is so simple. Open a UIViewController class and or create an outlet UIView

Comment: That could not have been the issue... Lol Anyways... Good Luck.